# Should HTTP Basic Authentication be used for client or user API authentication?

Tags: api, rest, authentication, basic-authentication

A typical recommendation for securing a REST API is to use HTTP Basic Authentication over SSL. My question is, should HTTP Basic Authentication only be used to authenticate the **client** (ie. the app accessing the API), or can it also be used to authenticate the **user** (the consumer of the app)?

It seems most APIs have to deal with both, as almost all web services employ some sort of user accounts. Just consider Twitter or Vimeo—there are public resources, and there are private (user specific) resources.

It seems logical that a simple REST API could do both client and user authentication at the same time using using HTTP Basic Authentication (over SSL).

Is this a good design?

Answer (score 0):

By authenticate the client you probably mean the usage of API Key, this mechanism is used to track the concrete application/client. The second  thing is that it gives you the possibility to disable the application by disabling the key, for example when client's author removes his account from the service. If you want to make your API public then it is a good idea.

But you need to remember that it gives you no real protection, everybody can download the client and extract that key.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to use Basic Authentication for API authentication. When it comes to authentication then you should consider that the application (client) developer has to implement its side of the authentication, too. Part of that is not only authentication itself but also how to get credentials and even much more than that.

I recommend to make use of an established authentication standard that ships with client libraries for the most popular programming languages. Those libraries make it much more likely that developers are going to adapt your API, because they reduce implementation effort on the client side.

Another important reason for using authentication standards is that they make developers (and others) more confident in the security of your authentication system. Those standards have been audited by experts and their weaknesses and strengths are well known and documented. It is unlikely that you are going to develop a nearly as solid authentication flow unless you are a security expert :-).

The most established standard in this field is [OAuth](http://oauth.net/) but you can find alternatives by searching for "oauth alternatives".

**How does OAuth help you with your problem setting?**

In OAuth 2, the application client has to obtain an access token for a user before accessing any protected resource. To get an access token, the application must authenticate itself with its application credentials. Depending on the use-case (e.g. 3rd party, mobile) this is done in different ways that are defined by the OAuth standard.

An access token should not only represent a user but also which operations may be used on what resources (permissions). A user may grant different permissions to different applications so this information must somehow be linked to the token.

How to achieve such a semantic for access tokens however is not part of OAuth - **it just defines the flow of how to obtain access tokens.** Therefor, the implementation of the access token semantic is usually application specific.

You can implement such token semantic by storing a link between an access tokens and its permissions in your backend when you create the access token. The permissions may either be stored for every user-application combination or just for every application, depending on how fine-granular you want things to be.

Then, each time that an access token is processed by the API, you fetch this information and check whether the user has sufficient permissions to access the resource and to perform the desired operation.

Another option is to put the permission information into the access token and to sign or encrypt the token. When you receive the access token, you verify or decrypt it and use the permissions that are stored in the access token to make your decision. You may want to have a look on [Json Web Tokens (JWT)](http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html) on how to accomplish that.

The benefit of the later solution is better scalability and less effort during backend implementation. The downside of it are potentially larger requests (especially with RSA encryption) and less control over tokens.